# *ngIf with focus directive

Tags: angular, input, focus, angular-ng-if

In my app, I tried to place a button that shows/hides an `input` field with a `boolean` component property. If the button shows the `input`, focus should be set on the `input`. But it seems not to work. If I remove the `*ngIf` the focus directive works fine.

I created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ij73xfOI2vzUDn83cm6p?p=preview) that shows what I mean. It's kind of difficult to describe my problem.

**HTML in a component:**

```
<input *ngIf="filterShow.options"
       [focus]="filterFocus.options"
       [(ngModel)]="filter.options">

<button type="button"
        (click)="setShowFilter('options')">
  focus
</button>
```

**`setShowFilter()` method:**

```
private setShowFilter(filter: string) {
  this.filterShow[filter] = !this.filterShow[filter];

  /* reset filter */
  this.filter[filter] = "";

  this.filterFocus[filter].emit(true);
}
```

**`focus.directive.ts`:**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[focus]'
})
export class FocusDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input('focus') focusEvent: EventEmitter<boolean>;

  constructor(private elementRef : ElementRef,
              private renderer   : Renderer   ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.focusEvent.subscribe(event => {
      this.renderer
        .invokeElementMethod(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`EventEmitter`s are for `@Output`s, not for `@Input`s.  Try something like this instead:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[focus]'
})
export class FocusDirective implements OnChanges {

  @Input('focus') focus: boolean;

  constructor(private elementRef : ElementRef,
              private renderer   : Renderer   ) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.focus) {
      this.renderer
        .invokeElementMethod(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you are using event emitters wrong. they are for child -> parent communication, not for parent -> child.  What I posted works for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/YtaRtA0e5L6ewxq7uCH9?p=preview

Comment: `Renderer` and it's `.invokeElementMethod()` method have been deprecated as this point in time.  It is now safe to call `this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus()` directly.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time, it doesn't work because the focus event is followed by other events. So the element lost focus. We need to use `setTimeout` in order to put it at the end of the Task Scheduler queue:

```
import { Directive, OnChanges, Input, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[focus]'
})
export class FocusDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input('focus') focus: boolean;

  constructor(private elementRef : ElementRef) { }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.focus) {
      setTimeout(() => { this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus(); }, 0);      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to achieve this without having to use a directive is to use `<label>` instead of `<button>` and use css to style it like a button. For example,

`<label for="myInput"></label>
 <input id="myInput"></input>`

This way you can achieve focus even with the presence of `*ngIf` because the `<input>` is now bound to the `<label>`. [Also, Angular2 documentation website warns about the use of `ElementRef` because of the security vulnerability it poses.](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html)